# Liberar Puerto 88 usado por kerberos (krb5, kerberos-sec) para instalar Directorio Activo

Tags: directorioactivo, windows-server

Quiero instalar el directorio activo en **Windows Server 2008 R2**, uso el comando
`dcpromo` y comienza a instalar lo binario pero al rato me dice que no puede instalar porque los puertos listados (solo 1) está ocupado, que debo liberarlo antes de poder instalar, al verificar la lista encuentro este:

> 88 kerberos (krb5, kerberos-sec)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Busqué en la consola la aplicación que lo está usando y es el System, y según leí, lo usa para la autenticación en red con otros equipos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Mil gracias de antemano.

--

[Misma Pregunta colocada en foro de Microsoft](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/10ce10a9-1284-4564-a3ac-21088a697f5e/liberar-puerto-88-usado-por-kerberos-krb5-kerberossec-para-instalar-directorio-activo?forum=wsades)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resulta que el servidor tiene el IIS, y una de las páginas web le habían colocado que ingresara por el puerto 88, solo cambié el puerto de esta página y listo, funcionó